# Toggle editing does not work for Digitizing forms in QGIS

Tags: qgis, editing, digitizing

I have QGIS 3.32.3-Lima under Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.
I created a new GeoPackage layer to draw a rectangle. I hence added the tool bar "Digitizing forms" as well as the tool bar "Advanced digitizing". Both tool bars were grey. I then toggled editing. The tool bar "Advanced digitizing" was not grey anymore, but the tool bar "Digitizing forms" remained grey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the "Shape Digitizing Toolbar" it will only activate if :

- You are currently editing a Line or Polygon layer (it can't work with
  point so it won't activate with point layer),
- You have the "Add Line feature" or "Add Polygon feature" tool
  selected (you need to select the tool that let you add a new feature before selecting the shape you want to add).

Note that after using the Shape Digitizing Toolbar you have to change the digitizing option to something else than "Digitize Shape" to stop using the Shape Digitizing Toolbar.

Below the "Add Polygon feature" tool and digitizing option button (with the Digitize Shape option selected) are circled in red.

[image]